# Include one HTML file in another HTML file using client side include

Tags: html, jquery

I am a beginner and I have a static page where I want to include other Html files. Like the header, footer, some buttons, and a form that I am using on more than one page.
I am not allowed to use the server-side for this exercise. So I tried using jQuery but it didn't work.
But I also would like some way to include these files without making a wrapper for them. But will be happy even with the wrapper divs if you guys help me with that.

I have not used jQuery before but I feel like a have tried every way that I found. You can see all of them below.
*I am using jQuery 3.5.1.min if it is of importance.*

```
$(".header").load("_header.html")
```

```
$(function () {
    $(".header").load("_header.html");
});
```

```
function unWrapPlaceholder() {
   $(this).contents().unwrap();
}

$(function () {
 $("#header").load("_header.html", unWrapPlaceholder);
});
```

```
$(function(){
    var includes = $('[data-include]');
    jQuery.each(includes, function(){
      var file = '../views/' + $(this).data('include') + '.html';
      $(this).load(file);
    });
  });

<div data-include="_header"></div>
```

I don't want to use the object tag or iframes. Are there any suggestions or corrections you can give me?
I would really appreciate the help.

**The file location was the problem! In the end I used the second jQuery code.**

Comment: what happens when you use `$(function () {
    $(".header").load("_header.html");
});` It should work fine. Pass the callback function and check the response as shown [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Double check the HTML file location, You want to load.

Comment: Yes after the first comment I started to search for a mistake and found that the file location was the problem. I appreciate your comments.